# SerialPort send missing characters

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am new to C# and C# forms.

I have form made in C# which has several forms inside which I open according to requirement.
When I send data through serial port then some characters are missing on the receiving end(micro controller in my case).

Please help me in finding the possible reasons or solution.
Do I need to create delegate for this.

I use the following line to send data.

`portToUse.SendASCIIString("USC,TR,1,E,N,1,30,30,4,4,8\r");`

Following string received in which comma is missing between E & N:

```
USC,TR,1,EN,1,30,30,4,4,8\r
```

Comment: I had never seen such a problem in C#. There are two possible explanations: 1. your code to send data has a bug and corrupt the data, or the receiver has a problem receiving the data. Since there is no method `SendASCIIString` in the [class `SerialPort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.7.2), please add your code of `SendASCIIString` and when possible add more details (code) from the receiver. In Linux based system, two application can open and read from the same serial port. This can also be the issue.

Comment: Thank you reply.
I forgot to mention. I am using ZylSerialPort component which has SendASCIIString method.
   
public static ZylSerialPort.SerialPort portToUse = new ZylSerialPort.SerialPort();

Comment: Try a few more combinitions of characters, can this be reproduced steadily?

Comment: I have tried few combination of characters and found that it is missing some characters in all the cases. I have also tried  portToUse.ClearOutputBuffer() before sending the characters.

Comment: Is there any pattern in the missing character? Like it is always the 10th char in the string?

Comment: Does the controller configured to use a flow control? See [Serial HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-4.html#flow_control) article on the Linux Documentation Project.